# Transfering Data from Calendar to New Calendar

Tags: 2013, list, calendar, export, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar in SharePoint 2013 and created a new calendar but I would like to have the data from the old calendar in the new calendar.  One solution I thought of was exporting the information into excel spreadsheet and transferring it into the new calendar.

Does anyone know the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tests.  The best way this can be done is by creating a template and transferring it to the new site collection.